# Write and read on pipe a list of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, linux

I want to write on a pipe an array with an unknown size.The array's values are read from stdin. Below is a part of the code that i have written so far. The problem is that using the `count` variable i am writing exactly 0 bytes. When i should allocate memory for the array in which i perform the read? It's there a better way to make this work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){

int fd[2];
int *values;
int *received;
pid_t child;
int count = 0;
if(pipe(fd) != 0){
    perror("pipe");
}
if((child = fork()) < 0){
    perror("fork");
}
else if(child == 0)
{
    close(fd[0]);

    while(enteringValues){
        //get values from stdin
        //allocating memory for each read element
        count++;
    }
    write(fd[1],values,count*sizeof(values[0]));
    close(fd[1]);
    exit(0);
}
close(fd[1]);
int i;
int nbytes = read(fd[0],&received,count*sizeof(received[0]));
for(i = 0;i<count;i++){
    printf("%d received \n",received[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes send bytes from one place to another. So you need to precisely specify what bytes you are going to send. Then make sure your sending code sends precisely those bytes and your receiving code expects precisely those bytes.

If you want it to work without having to do things the right way, do this:

Sender:

```
write(f[1], &val, sizeof(int));
```

Receiver:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  read(f[0], &buf[i], sizeof(int));
```

Note also printf("%d", *buff); prints the first element in the array (element zero).

Do not change the receiving code to read(f[0], buf, 3 * sizeof(int));. Your write is not atomic (because you call write three times) so you can't expect your read to be.

Comment: So you are telling me that if i want to send an array i have to send one element at a time? call write function for each element?

Comment: And what if a have 2 child processes, each one sending an array of different dimensions, writing one element at a time, how it's going to be the read?